# Task execution in distributed environment

Tags: distributed

I have a table say employee(id, name, email, is_email_verified, created_date). I need to send an email everyday for the users which has been created and email is not verified. I need to create a service which can be deployed on two boxes. It will read the user table and get the user id and send the mail for verification. Since, there are two boxes and each will read the same number of users and hence will send the two mails.

How, can we make this service so as user ids will get distributed among the servers (if I have n servers).

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do that.

**The most straightforward & reliable:**

1. Create a job task that read all user ID from the table and queue them to a task queue - 1 task per user ID.
2. Pull task from queue using as many servers as you want (1-N).

**Not requiring queues (not fault tolerant):**

Choose a hash function that would decide which user IDs should server process. For example 1st server processes odd IDs and 2nd even IDs, etc. Or something  like:

```
def should_i_send(user_id, server_id):
  return user_id % server_id == 0
```

Comment: Not sure I got your point as you can have as many pullers as you want.

Comment: For the second approach, how service_id should be determined if all the services are the same? Somehow, a center in a distributed environment should assign a different service_id to each replica server and should communicate that number down to server?

Answer (score 0):

You could add two new columns (`server_id`, `mail_status`) to your table and also give each server a unique number to be used as `server_id`. Then, you could use the following flow:

- Each server reads unsent records (by using `mail_status`) regardless of `server_id`.
- Then update the records with `server_id` as their id, `mail_status` as `PROCESSING`.
- Read all `PROCESSING` records where `server_id` equals to id of instance. Try to send mail based on each one successively. Based on the result of the execution, update the records either as `SUCCESS` or `ERROR`

Note that if you're using kubernetess environments, assigning each instance a `server_id` and communicating this down to the app could be challenging. This question searchs on this challenge [Task distribution across replicas of microservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76086264/task-distribution-across-replicas-of-microservices)