# Task distribution across replicas of microservices

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, distributed-computing

I have a legacy .net application that run as multiple instances each having different `service_id` hardcoded into each instances' server. With the help of `service_id` assigned to each instance, they are able to read some task information kept on a database table having columns (`id`, `task_content`, `service_id`, `task_status`) and execute some long running job.

`task_status` represents the status of task as `INITIAL`, `PROCESSING`, `PROCESSED`, `ERROR`.

Distribution of task is as follows:

- Each app instances periodically read the tasks with status equal to `INITIAL` regardless of `service_id` and update those records with new status as `PROCESSING` and `service_id` as the number assigned to the instance.
- Then they read `PROCESSING` tasks and `service_id` equal to their assigned number and execute the job
- Then they update the status of task either as `PROCESSED` or `ERROR`.

This way, they are sharing tasks across each instance and each app does execute tasks only belongs to its instance.

My task is to add some other instances by rewriting in java/spring framework (preserving already running legacy apps) and deploy as pods to kubernetess environment where I cannot give to unique number (`service_id`) to enumerate them.

If I somehow enumerate a running container uniquely across all instances I can use this enumeration as `service_id`. Is there a way to achieve this or what other workarounds to apply?

Note that I am not allowed to use any third party task distribution software.

Comment: Since you said the app instances read any task in INITIAL state regardless of service_id, why are you bothering with service_id assignments while creating these tasks? You can add as many app instances as you want then.

Comment: @Salil that is the first step, in the second step it updates those records with service id